# Let $\mathcal{P}_n$ denote the space of polynomials of degree $n$. One-to-one? Onto?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, vector-spaces, vectors

Question: Let $\mathcal{P}_n$ denote the space of polynomials of degree $n$.
$$\mathcal{P}_n = \{ p_0 + p_1 x + p_2x^2 + \cdots p_nx^n\}.$$
Define $\mathcal{L}:\mathcal{P}_n \to \mathcal{P}_{n-1}$ by differentiation. That is, $\mathcal{L}p = p'$.

1. Is this transformation one-to-one?
2. Is it onto?
3. Find the matrix representation of $\mathcal{L}$ supposing we use the standard monomial bases $\{x^i\}_{i=1}^n$ for $\mathcal{P}_n$ and $\{x^i\}_{i=1}^{n-1}$ for $\mathcal{P}_{n-1}$.

I have found a useful [document](https://www.math.drexel.edu/%7Etolya/derivative) to read about this as it relates to differentiation of polynomials and representing them as a matrix.

Here is what I know (and have come to know). A polynomial $p(x) \in \mathcal{P}_n$ can be represented by the $(n + 1) \times (n+1)$ identity matrix and the polynomials $q(x) \in\mathcal{P}_{n-1}$ can be represented by an $n\times n$ matrix under the constraints $\begin{cases}a_{ij} = 0 \quad \text{if } i \neq j \\ a_{11} = 0 \\ a_{ll} = a_{l-1}a_{l-1} + 1\end{cases}$ for $2 \leq l \leq n$. Consider a polynomial in $\mathcal{P}_k$ where $k = 2$. We have a matrix representation for $\mathcal{P}_k$ and $\mathcal{P}_{k-1}$ respectively.
$$\left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 & 0  \\ 0 & 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right] \text{ and } \left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{matrix}\right].$$
Then, this looks like the transformation would be one-to-one and invertible because each matrix is row equivalent to $I_n$. But, I am not really sure how to show that it is one-to-one and onto.

For (c), how I understand it, we need to find the matrix of $\mathcal{L}$ that takes a polynomial in $\mathcal{P}_n$ and maps it into $\mathcal{P}_{n-1}$. for example, take $\mathcal{P}_3$ and we have a matrix representation as
$$\left[\begin{matrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right].$$
Then let $p(x) = p_0 + p_1x + p_2x^2 \in \mathcal{P}_2$ be represented as $\left[\begin{matrix} p_0 \\ p_1 \\ p_2 \end{matrix}\right]$. Observe,
$$\mathcal{L}p(x) = \mathcal{L}\left(\left[\begin{matrix} p_0 \\ p_1 \\ p_2 \end{matrix}\right]\right) = \left[\begin{matrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix} p_0 \\ p_1 \\ p_2 \end{matrix}\right] = p_1 + 2p_2x.$$
Our desired formula for $p'(x)$.

Let me know if I am thinking about this correctly! I appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: you seem confused about that document. it does *not* say that elements/vectors/polynomials in $\mathcal{P}_n$ are represented by $n\times n$ matrices. It says that they are represented by $(n+1)\times 1$ column vectors!

Comment: Gotcha. That would be an accurate evaluation of my understanding :) I am a bit confused in the Matrix theory class. @ArturoMagidin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P_n$ should be the space of polynomials of degree at most $n$. $P_k$ is a vector space so it doesn't make sense to have a matrix representation for it; matrix representations are for linear maps. Note that $\dim P_n = n + 1$ and $\dim P_{n - 1} = n$. Therefore the matrix $A_n$ that represents $L \colon P_n \to P_{n - 1}$ is $n \times (n + 1)$. For $n = 2$, we have $L1 = 0$, $Lx = 1$, $Lx^2 = 2x$. Thus the matrix representation of $L \colon P_2 \to P_1$ with respect to the bases $\{1, x, x^2\}$ of $P_2$, and $\{1, x\}$ of $P_1$ is
$$A_3 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2\\ \end{pmatrix}.$$
You can use the matrix $A_n$ to determine whether $L \colon P_n \to P_{n - 1}$ is one to one and onto since $L$ is one to one if and only if $A_n$ is and $L$ is onto if and only if $A_n$ is.

Comment: I see! Thank you for the clarification!